# Installing xattr PECL extension in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, pecl, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to install extension `xattr` in my Ubuntu 12.10 .

`sudo pecl install xattr`

But I am getting the error as :

```
checking for xattr files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libattr distribution
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/xattr/configure --with-xattr' failed
```

How do I correct this error and install `xattr` in LAMP ?

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libattr1-dev
```

Then simply rerun the "sudo pecl install xattr" command and you should be set.